# NextJs image from markdown metadata or frontmatter

Tags: image, markdown, next.js

I need to load the image coming from the markdown metadata

```
---
title: 'First Blog'
description: 'First blog description'
image: ../../common/src/assets/image/image.png
author: 'Stack'
---
```

When i pass this to my code the and inspect the browser, the image src is just the path below. it's not converting to the static/... as usual for the other images

```
<img src={post.frontmatter.image} />
```

How do i get this fixed without using any plugins like next-images. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nextjs can serve images under a folder called public in your root directory.
Add a folder to your root call it "public" and Add your assets to it

EXAMPLE:

```
public
--common
----src
------assets
--------image
----------image.png
```

```
---
image: "/common/src/assets/image/image.png"
---
```

```
---
<img src={post.frontmatter.image} />
---
```

Nextjs will take care of the rest for you.
More on [Static File Serving](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/static-file-serving)